# link not loading in iframe after the first time

Tags: php, html, css

Im new to using iframes and i have encountered a problem i don't really understand. I have a navigation bar and an iframe. Once I click one link "Search", the link does get loaded into the iframe and i am able to work in there but if i click "Search" again or "Form" the links open in another tab. How can I stop that from happening and just reload into iframe?

```
<div id="container">
        <ul id="leftnav">
            <li>
                <a href="search.php" target="admin_frame">Search!</a>
            </li>
            <li>                    
                <a href="form.php" target="admin_frame">Form</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;



        <div id="iframe">
        <iframe  id ="admin_frame" name="admin_frame" width="99%" height= "100%"></iframe>
        </div>



    </div>
```

Search.php

This page allows the user to upload a list of names that is then parsed in  parse_csv.php. Once the list of names is put in an array, I use a javascript API to fetch information then send it to php using AJAX. I am able to get a confirmation and everything works properly. this is all happening in the iframe so when I click "Search" to upload another list, it opens in another window.

```
<body>
<div class="left">
    <h3>Upload list.</h3>   
        <h4 style="color:red">File to upload must be <a href="" onclick="openWin()">.csv</a></h4>
        <form action="parse_csv.php" method = "POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="list" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>
        </form>
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: Do you have any code in click event of 'Search' link at all?

Comment: are you setting the 'src' property of the iframe everytime search is clicked?

Comment: @JasonLokiSmith if i don't want anything inside the iframe initially, do I still need the 'src'? Would it be a blank html page? I tried it and i still get the same problem.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Search.php does contain code to upload a file. I will edit to add it.

Answer (score 0):

sandbox="allow-same-origin"

use this attribute it won't happen again